# Unable install rails in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: package-management, ruby, rails

I am trying to install rails in my ubuntu 12.10, but I am unsuccessful in doing it. I am getting the error about packages. Here is the sample exmple

```
 E: Unable to locate package libsql
```

What I did was, I installed ubuntu recently along side of windows7. I going through these E: W: N: package errors. I dont know what sort of errors are these.  Please help!

Comment: What command are you running and you get the E: error?

Comment: I am following the steps to install rails, while doing so I came across these errors... 

sudo apt-get -y install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsql

Comment: Can you try and run the following command instead: `sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev \
curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 \
libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison  \
subversion pkg-config`

Comment: I tried and came across these errors 
E: Unable to locate package  curl
E: Unable to locate package  libxml2-dev
E: Unable to locate package  subversion

Comment: Read the answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/277708/i-downloaded-ruby-on-rails-but-it-says-it-isnt-installed/277713#277713

Answer (score 0):

I have just done two Rails 3 installs on Ubuntu 12.04. If you want to try the procedure in 12.10 the link to the page is

http://polyoperable.cmready.com/?p=300

The blog writer seemed to know what he was talking about as both installs were without a hitch.

Good luck and let us know,
Bernie